# Django queryset.filter() does not work on intersection() result

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm having issues with `queryset.intersection(...).filter(...)`. I found that the `filter()` call does simply not do anything, but returns the same results as the `queryset.intersection()`.

I now present an illustrative example. `minex/models.py` file:

```
from uuid import uuid4

from django.db import models


class Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Release(models.Model):
    version = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    channels = models.ManyToManyField(to=Channel, related_name='releases')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.uuid:
            self.uuid = str(uuid4())

        super(Release, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Serial(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    releases = models.ManyToManyField(to=Release, related_name='serials', blank=True)
```

Illustration of the problem: `dbtest.py`

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'minexample.settings')
from minexample.wsgi import application
from minex.models import Serial, Release, Channel

channel = Channel.objects.create(name="stable")

r1 = Release.objects.create(version="1.0")
r1.channels.add(channel)
r06 = Release.objects.create(version="0.6.2")
r06.channels.add(channel)

serial = Serial.objects.create(name="Some Serial")
serial.releases.add(r06)

releases = serial.releases.all().intersection(channel.releases.all())

assert r1 not in releases  # works as expected

assert not releases.filter(uuid=r1.uuid).exists()  # assertion failed... why?
```

Note: the last assertion does not fail if we instead did `releases = serial.releases`. The problem seems to be that I'm calling `intersection()`. I also stepped into Django's code and the WHERE statement does not contain the `uuid=r1.uuid` at all... Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe you need to `refresh_from_db()` before assert

Comment: From the documentation this call would be made if you expect the database content to have changed in the meantime. In my above example this cannot be the cause. I perform all DB-modifications first. The last 3 lines are only queries.

Answer (score 0):

Django now gives an error informing that `filter()` is not supported after applying `intersection()`:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31227